# "Here I go" in the context of death

Tags: meaning, word-choice, expressions

I am interested in the different usages of "here I go" when used in a more abstract sense.

It apparently used some times before death, examples here – [Famous Last Words](https://www.djsmapping.com/words.shtml)
or also in some lyrics – [AURORA: Murder song](https://genius.com/Aurora-murder-song-5-4-3-2-1-lyrics)

Is this usage archaic or still permissible nowadays?

Comment: It's not at all archaic, but it is normally used in the context of making a jump or launching yourself into some kind of activity. It would be rather flippant to use it when you were expecting to die.

Comment: It seems a strange question. There is no acceptable formula or etiquette rule for what you say when you're dying. Last words (at least those on lists) are often ironic or witty. You mention "abstract" usages, so are you thinking about "here I go" in some context in addition to lists of famous last words? I think the question of why someone might say "here I go" when dying is outside the scope of this board.

Comment: @StuartF Yes I’m afraid I was not clear here — I’ve meant would this still be permissible today to write in the context of (impending) death, let’s say in a story or screenplay.

Comment: I'd guess it would be ok, but it would depend on situation and on the person saying it. As Kate Bunting says "here I go" in other contexts is perfectly normal.

Comment: It is quoted twice on the page that you linked to, and how many people have died since the dawn of time? It is not common. It is definitely not idiomatic. Can you use it? Sure, but don't expect any greater impact than the fact a dying person is saying it.